# Custom CFileDialog in visual studio 2013 (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am porting one of our applications from VS 2005 to VS 2013. In this application we customized the CFileDialog dialog in this way:

```
    class CFileStart : public CFileDialog 
    ...
    INT_PTR CFileStart::DoModal ()
    {
        m_ofn.lpTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_START );
        m_ofn.Flags |= OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE;
        m_ofn.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle ();
        return CFileDialog::DoModal ();
    }
```

It uses to works fine with visual studio 2005 but it doesn't work on Vs2013. Any Idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? Throws error? No display?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem passing false to bVistaStyle in the CFileDialog constructor.